# Imported database and can not add data because of primary key

Tags: javascript, mysql

Good morning everyone!
I've imported my database from my laptop to my computer. On my website when I try to register a new user im getting this error:

```
Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I am sure that happens because my computer starts to count the primary key (a field called `id`) from 0 again (and that doesn't match with the users already loaded in the database).

That's my Register Controller:

```js
// Register Controller
exports.register = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)

    const { username, email, password, passwordConfirm } = req.body;

    db.query('SELECT username,email FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?', [username,email], async (error, results) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        if( results.length > 0 ){
            
            return res.render('register', {
                message: 'The username or email already exists'
            })
        } else if( password !== passwordConfirm){
            return res.render('register', {
                message: 'Passwords do not match'
            })
        }

        let hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password,8);


        db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', {username: username, email: email, password: hashPassword, admin: 0}, (error,results) => {
            if(error) {
                console.log(error)
            } else {
                console.log(results)
                return res.render('register', {
                    message: 'User registered'
                })
            }

        })
    })
```

My database:
[image]

Also bonus question:

My second user is added directly in to the database without using `Register Controller` because it is an admin account. Any way to hash the password of already loaded field?

After using the comments i added this function
Let me post my function so you can have an idea

```js
async function findId() {
  db.query("SELECT COUNT(id) as id FROM users", (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    } else {
      console.log(results)
      res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))
      console.log(res[0].id)
      let check = res[0].id
      return check
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course since you have direct access to the DB, you may directly hash the password (so yes, is basically possible hash a field directly from phpmyadmin *since the engine support it, just use a simple SET query!*).

More information can be found [HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html).

About your first question, since the table struct require the "id" field as primary key, you have three solution:

1. [Try to read the last](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/sql/sql_func_last.asp.html#gsc.tab=0) "id" value from the table, and add the new users (the ones you are try to import) after the last one already on the DB
2. [*] Cycle and [count every field](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/sql/sql_func_count.asp.html#gsc.tab=0) and append the users on the table. (Example: if you have 5 users already on DB, just count it, add +1 at the value and start to adding the users after the 5th element, of course you lost the original ID value)
3. overwrite existing id (just set WHERE id = id_you_are_try_to_import)

Post the table structure of your DB may help us to find a good solution! Think about it next time

[*] **simple concept in pseudo-code about implementation:**

Here you have the query that add the user...

```
db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', {username: username, email: email, password: hashPassword, admin: 0}, (error,results) => 
{
    if(error) 
    {
        console.log(error)
    } else 
    {
        console.log(results)
        return res.render('register', 
        {
            message: 'User registered'
        })
}
```

I guess you can force the "id" to be the next one, after you counted all items already presents. Just send a `COUNT()` query and store the count value in a variable and then add +1 to it:

```
* SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name;

// which began:

* SELECT COUNT('id') FROM users; // this return the number of "id" present in the db...
```

... add +1 at this value to force id to be the next one, so you can append new accounts

Comment: hello and thanks for the response. The past hour i was trying to solve it with the Count method. The problem is i can find my last id but because of the asynchronous coding i cannot use that ID inside my Insert Query

Comment: What about send sync query and pass the result at this function as parameter? Plus i've seen `async (error, results)` in the SELECT query, but i didn't find it on the INSERT one ... so? Is this sync or async request ... you should post the entire code

Comment: what im trying is calling
`let id = await findId()` Where findId is an asynchronous function that counts my id(working).My next db.query the insert one, shouldnt have to wait my id to finish first?

Comment: This is the entire code for creating a new user.

Comment: Yea, that's a solution, or you may send a function first which return the numbers of the users counted and pass it in the findID as parameter. Like : `let id = await findId(usersCounted)` where `usersCounted` is the number of users already present on the DB, returned from a previous query/function

Comment: added my extra function in the original post.

Comment: await for this function to be finished should solve your problem... in my opinion, by the way, is not a good implementation since it may require time if you start to have many users. Better try to implement `LAST()` and get the user code. You can find clarification of it in the original response i made :)

Comment: LAST() only works in MS Access i used the mysql syntax which is order by and desc limit 1. Working but still doesnt wait for my function to finish and i get this
[link](https://i.imgur.com/ihSsBnp.png) . As you can see from the screenshot the first console.log should be last.

Comment: Yes, i've posted that solution cause it has a workaround for every type of engine. By the way, (just for test purpose) have you tried to send request synchronous

Comment: no i didnt try it.